# Webapp deployed in Glassfish can't write to files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ubuntu, permissions, glassfish

I have the following function inside a Stateless EJB running in Glassfish. All it does is write some data to a file. The first part of the function just creates the path to where the file needs to go. The second part actually writes the file.

```
private boolean createFile(String companyName, String fileName, byte[] data)
{
    logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Creating file: {0} for company {1}", new Object[]{fileName, companyName});
    File companyFileDir = new File(LOCAL_FILE_DIR, companyName);
    if(companyFileDir.exists() == false)
    {
        boolean createFileDir = companyFileDir.mkdirs();
        if(createFileDir == false)
        {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Could not create directory to place file in");
            return false;
        }
    }
    File newFile = new File(companyFileDir, fileName);
    try 
    {
        FileOutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        fileWriter.write(data);
    } 
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Could not write file to disk",e);
        return false;
    }
    logger.log(Level.FINEST,"File successfully written to file");
    return true;
}
```

The output I get after this code executes is:

```
WARNING: Could not create directory to place file in
```

So obviously Glassfish cant create this directory. I am am assuming this has something to do with permissions. Can anyone give me a direction to go as to what might be wrong here?

I am running this on Glassfish 3.12 on Ubuntu 12

Answer (score 0):

different things:
1) Compare spec: (21.1.2 Programming Restrictions)
An enterprise bean must not use the java.io package to attempt to access ﬁles and directories in the ﬁle system.
I'm sure GF isn't enforcing this, but you should be aware of that.

2) The code itself is fine. Try chmod +777 on the LOCAL_FILE_DIR to get an idea if it has to do with rights in general ...

Hope that helps ...